# Combining rows of a dataframe base on the values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

How can I combine the Percentage Total Production that are less than 20% into 1 row and label that as 'Others'

so i should only get 'Other': 78.43%, India: 21.561239%
The results should be in a dataframe in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate a row that is the sum of all rows where the percentage is < 20, and all the remaining rows:

```py
mask = df['Percentage_Total_Production'] < 20
new_row = pd.DataFrame([df[mask].sum(axis=0)], index=['other'])

pd.concat([new_row, df[~mask]], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column to mask the data. Taking into account if the percentage is < 0.2:

```
df["New Index"] = np.where(df["Percentage_Total_Production"] < 0.2, "Other", df["Percentage_Total_Production"].index)
```

And then, apply a `.groupby()` transformation:

```
df.groupby("New Index").sum()
```